# plotting countour profiles in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data composed by three 1d-arrays (X,Y,Z) and I want to create a graph like the origin contour profile (https://www.originlab.com/doc/Origin-Help/Contour-Profile), where I have a 3d data plotted in a 2d contour, where the z value is represented by the graphic colors, and two other graphs representing profiles (or slices) of my surface for specific x and y-values. My problem is how to create the profiles.

I started by creating new x and y arrays and a grid surface for z by interpolating the data I had with `scipy.interpolate.griddata`

and now I can create the contour plot but I don't know how to create the profiles in xz and yz planes. I found out how to this in a 3d plot by using `zdir=x` and `zdir=y` (https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/mplot3d/contour3d_3.html) but this works only for 3d graphs. I also know that I can trace the profile in the 'xy' plane for a specific z-value with `ax.contour(x, y, z, [zvalue])`. I want to do something similar to the 'xz' and 'yz' planes.

The code I have is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

# reading the data
path = 'data/2019_12_11_15h17m29s_TZO_1Nd_3Hz_ref_900nm_900mW.txt_output.dat'
df = pd.read_csv(path)

X = df.position
Y = df.time
Z = df.signal

# interpolating data to create a surface
xi = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 100)
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), 100)
zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='linear')
zi = np.nan_to_num(zi)

# if I want to plot a 2D contour plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.contourf(xi, yi, zi, levels=300, cmap="RdBu_r")
plt.show()

# if I want to plot a 3d surface with profiles
xi2, yi2 = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(xi2, yi2, zi, rstride=3, cstride=3, alpha=0.5)

cset = ax.contour(xi2, yi2, zi, zdir='x', offset=X.min()-30, cmap=cm.coolwarm, levels=10)
cset = ax.contour(xi2, yi2, zi, zdir='y', offset=Y.max()+30, cmap=cm.coolwarm, levels=10)

ax.set_xlim(X.min()-30, X.max()+30)
ax.set_ylim(Y.min()-30, Y.max()+30)
ax.set_zlim(Z.min(), Z.max())

plt.show()

# if I want to make a profile in xy plane:
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes()
ax.contour(xi, yi, zi, [1])
plt.show()
```

but I don't know how to create the profiles in 'xz' and 'yz' planes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a way of doing it that is not exactly what I was looking for but works perfectly. The idea is to fix a column/row of `zi` and plot against `xi`/`yi` to do a profile of the xz/yz plane. Varying the column/row in a for loop I got a result similar to levels of contour plot:

```
for i in range(0,len(zi),step):
   z_xz = zi[i,:]
   plt.plot(xi,z_xz)
```

and

```
for i in range(0,len(zi[0]),step):
   z_xz = zi[:,i]
   plt.plot(yi,z_xz)
```

please, let me know if you find a better solution